# how can i get all wall post on facebook through php?

Tags: php, facebook

i am using fql, and pass it in url for get all wall posts of a user on facebook.
i have passed this url

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20post_id%2C%20message%20from%20stream%20where%20source_id%3D12699262021

but it gives only 25 records.

i want to get all records(wall posts) of this user. how can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >) to retrieve a much greater range of posts.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/